# InvocableMethod - returning string value back to the flow

Tags: apex, invocable-method, invocablevariable

I want to return a string value back to the flow. Got it this far, and also I am able to get the return value when I am not in an invocable method.

Here is the error I am getting -
**Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getSalesforceBaseUrl() from the type Invocable_GetBaseUrl.BaseUrl**

What is wrong in the below code -

```
global with sharing class Invocable_GetBaseUrl {

    @InvocableMethod(
        label = 'Method to Extract Base URL'
        description = 'Method to Extract Base URL'
    )
    global static List<BaseUrl> GetBaseUrl() {      
        List<BaseUrl> baseUrl = new List<BaseUrl>();
        BaseUrl url = new BaseUrl();
        url.theBaseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
        baseUrl.add(url);        
        return baseUrl;
    }
            
    global class BaseUrl {
        @InvocableVariable(
            label = 'BaseUrl'
            description = 'Variable to store Base URL'
        )
        global String theBaseUrl;
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is an overloaded `URL` token

```
url.theBaseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
```

the compiler thinks that `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()` is referring to your declared variable `url`. Apex is not case sensitive

you can fix this in many ways. Here is an obvious one:

```
BaseUrl bUrl = new BaseUrl();
bUrl.theBaseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
baseUrl.add(bUrl); 
return baseUrl;
```

Or, you can do this:

```
    BaseUrl url = new BaseUrl();
    url.theBaseUrl = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
    baseUrl.add(url);
    return baseUrl;
```

Or, more O-O:

```
global static List<BaseUrl> GetBaseUrl() {      
    return new List<BaseUrl> {
           new BaseUrl(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm())
           };
}
        
global class BaseUrl {
    @InvocableVariable(
        label = 'BaseUrl'
        description = 'Variable to store Base URL'
    )
    global BaseUrl(String val) {this.theBaseUrl = val;}
    global String theBaseUrl;
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, was it that easy. Thanks cropredy

Comment: I gave you another option; see above

Comment: Thanks cropredy, that looks neat.